# Angular 4 - Change class in active element

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have the following button:

```
<button  class="icon-eoa-close pull-right" (click)="hideModal()" aria-label="Close" >
```

Here is the css:

```
.icon-eoa-close {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius:30px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #777;

}
.icon-eoa-close:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
.icon-eoa-close:hover {
    color: #41b97c;
}
.icon-eoa-close-c:active {
    color: #41b97c;
}
```

The `.icon-eoa-close` class references a font item, and I want to change the class to `.icon-eoa-close-c` when the button is clicked (active). How do I achieve this using Angular 4?

Comment: i found an adequate solution, however it involves the use of sass so it's not really what the question is asking here. but basically, if you're using sass, use a wrapper class (like say, `.modal-close`), and in the wrapper class you can use `@extend` on the classes you need. ie: `@extend .icon-eoa-close` on a normal button, `@extend .icon-eoa-close-c` on an active button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngClass, that's the recommended way, eg.:

```
<button [ngClass]="{'icon-eoa-close': isClosed, 'icon-eoa-close-c': !isClosed}"  class="pull-right" (click)="hideModal()" aria-label="Close" >
```

I'm not sure, but I think it should work with a shorthand as well:

```
<button [ngClass]="isClosed ? 'icon-eoa-close' : 'icon-eoa-close-p'"  class="pull-right" (click)="hideModal()" aria-label="Close" >
```

The first one must work!